# how to randomly show a high number of points in an area in R

Tags: r, random, raster, sample

I am trying to collect random sample points from an area (polygons) to later cross-check information from these points in a raster.
However, sometimes I need a high number of points.
When I try to run my code, R returns an error.

I used this code, which worked great for small numbers.

```
#create a set of random point samples

library(raster)
library(sp)
r_sample <- spsample(my_shp, n= 212183, type='random') 

#cross and extract raster information based on previously generated points
 
extrc <- raster::extract(my_raster, r_sample, small=T, na.rm=F) #extrair as quantidades de pixels
```

**error**

```
> r_sample <- spsample(controle, n= 212183 , type='random')
> Error: Unable to allocate vector of size 1.9 Gb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works for small numbers you can run it a couple of times

```
x <- lapply(1:10, function(i) spsample(controle, n= 21218 , type='random'))
```

And combine them like this:

```
y <- do.call(rbind, x)
```

Comment: Thanks, this idea of using a lapply from the applay family was really cool.